# Routes override with play2.4 maven libraryDependencies

Tags: maven, playframework-2.4

I've been trying to migrate my old and hardly usable play2.2 libraries, managed with subprojects structure, to a maven repository with separated projects and with play2.4

So far, whenever I add a project to another, to the libraryDependencies list, the routes from that project override the local routes.

So, for example, if the routing of the local project looks like this:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /fun                        controllers.FunController.fun

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(...)
```

And the one from the dependency project like this:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(...)
```

I end up with no "fun" call.

I know they are exactly the same, but that's the point, its not merging them or ignoring the incoming routes, which would be acceptable. It's overriding it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is fun() a static method.... 2.4 injecting dependency for each controller so no more static methods are required.

Comment: whoops, should have said this are Scala apps, no static methods.

Comment: I thought so... sorry not much knowledge with scala in plya apps.